# "Key not found" after fixing Python error: AttributeError: module 'sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration' has no attribute 'api_key' at Sendinblue.com

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib, sendinblue

I am trying to send e-mail campaign mails with the SMTP API of *Sendinblue.com*, a cloud-based marketing communication software suite. I am running my configuration of the template script provided by Sendinblue as seen on the screenshot:
[image: Sendinblue error: key not found]

My initial script was as follows:

```
# ------------------
# Create a campaign\
# ------------------
# Include the Sendinblue library\
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from datetime import datetime
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint
myapikey = 'xkeysib-.................................' # full api key
# Instantiate the client\
sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi()
# Define the campaign settings\
email_campaigns = sib_api_v3_sdk.CreateEmailCampaign(
name= "Campaign sent via the API",
subject= "My subject",
sender= { "name": "From name", "email": "------@gmail.com"}, # personal email with which I was registered @ sendinblue
type= "classic",
# Content that will be sent\
html_content= "Congratulations! You successfully sent this example campaign via the Sendinblue API.",
# Select the recipients\
recipients= {"listIds": [2, 7]},
# Schedule the sending in one hour\
scheduled_at = datetime.now()
)
# Make the call to the client\
try:
    api_response = api_instance.create_email_campaign(email_campaigns)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling EmailCampaignsApi->create_email_campaign: %s\n" % e)
```

I referred to [Sendinblue Documentation](https://developers.sendinblue.com/recipes/send-transactional-emails-in-python) in the cases where I had doubt. Most of the process seems self-explanatory, just the line with `configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'YOUR API KEY'`  was ambiguous as it is not quite clearly stated how exactly the api-key should be passed and the attribute of **api_key** I assumed **api_key** was holding the **name** of the API as defined in the [SMTP & API Advanced tab.](https://account.sendinblue.com/advanced/api) Even if I assume it should be holding some other values, it is not clear what they should be, what I can tell for sure is that sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration.api_key['api-key'] also resulted in `AttributeError: module 'sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration' has no attribute 'api_key'`.

After initially getting the error `AttributeError: module 'sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration' has no attribute 'api_key'` I researched a dozen of articles on StackOverflow, one of them on the Kubernetes topic where the script seemed to throw a similar error like the one I was getting, so I followed the advices described in *[Python kubernetes module has no attribute 'api_key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617162/python-kubernetes-module-has-no-attribute-api-key)*. Therefore, I tried reassigning the class attributes as follows:

```
configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi()
```

The fact that now I wasn't getting the error of a missing key but facing an *'unauthorized'* message cheered me up for a short time, until I spent several hours trying to get past this. So the script that's now throwing the `HTTP response body: {"message":"Key not found","code":"unauthorized"}` is now this:

```
# ------------------
# Create a campaign\
# ------------------
# Include the Sendinblue library\
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from datetime import datetime
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint
myapikey = 'xkeysib-c..............' # key
# Instantiate the client\
sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi()
# Define the campaign settings\
email_campaigns = sib_api_v3_sdk.CreateEmailCampaign(
name= "Campaign sent via the API",
subject= "My subject",
sender= { "name": "From name", "email": "mail....@gmail.com"}, # personal gmail with which I was initially registered @ sendinblue.com
type= "classic",
# Content that will be sent\
html_content= "Congratulations! You successfully sent this example campaign via the Sendinblue API.",
# Select the recipients\
recipients= {"listIds": [2, 7]},
# Schedule the sending in one hour\
scheduled_at = datetime.now()      
)
# Make the call to the client\
try:
    api_response = api_instance.create_email_campaign(email_campaigns)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling EmailCampaignsApi->create_email_campaign: %s\n" % e)
```

My 1st question is: was my 1st script wrong and in what way?
Secondly: Is `configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey` the correct syntax, assuming that 'api-sb' is the name of my API key as shown on the screenshot?
And third: In the `myapikey` variable, when assigning the API key itself, should there be anything else as a prefix to the key?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample transactional email script. Worked for me in python.

https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference/sendtransacemail

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```py
sib_api_v3_sdk.configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi()
```

do this:

```py
configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-sb'] = myapikey

api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.EmailCampaignsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))
```

as shown in https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference/createemailcampaign-1.